# Spring java-config way to configure login page redirect

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

Is there any analogues of Spring Security tags form-login/always-use-default-target and form-login/default-target-url in java config?
I'm trying to disable redirecting on login page by default, but the whole application is written using java configs and I don't wont to dive in xml's.